# How to Highlight image based on selection in JSF

Tags: jsf

The images are displayed horizontally using `<t:dataList>`. At first no images are selected if selected it has to be highlighted. If user changes the selection the old has to go normal and new has to be highlighted. while in edit mode we need to highlight the already selected image and they may change in this mode so highlight should change. Bean is in session scope. pls provide some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Primefaces Carousel](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/carousel.jsf)

Comment: Can we mix JSF RI 1.1 and Tamhawk and primefaces,etc in one application.

Comment: I don't know - try. And why don't you upgrade to 1.2 ?

Comment: We can mix other JSF libraries in one application visit it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552613/can-we-mix-jsf-ri-1-1-and-tamhawk-and-primefaces-etc-in-one-application