# Can we mix JSF RI 1.1 and Tamhawk and primefaces,etc in one application

Tags: jsf

Can we mix JSF RI 1.1 with Tomahawk, Primefaces, MyFaces, etc in one application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mix JSF *component libraries* (Tomahawk, RichFaces, PrimeFaces, etc), but you cannot mix JSF *implementations*. Sun RI and Apache MyFaces are both JSF implementations. You have to choose the one or other. Any component library ought to work flawlessly with any of the implementations. Which implementation to choose depends on whether it is solid and well-developed. For JSF 1.1, I'd suggest to pick MyFaces. For JSF 1.2 and 2.0, I'd suggest to pick Mojarra (the Sun RI).

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces does not support JSF 1.1., it has been designed for JSF 2.0 so we've decided not to support 1.1. at the beginning of the project. Yet JSF 1.2 is well supported.

Comment: Is earlier version of PrimeFaces works with JSF 1.1. If not what to do to have pagination in jsf 1.1. pls give some solution

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! I've seen you here before: http://stackoverflow.com/users/299800/cagatay-civici I recommend to register yourself, so that you can stick to one and same account.

Comment: Dear BalusC that is different and i am different. But unfortunately we both asked same question. Please believe me. That is different account. I thank you people for your wonderful work that you are doing. I ll be fervent to Stackoverflow.

Comment: No version of PrimeFaces supports JSF 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there's a lot of compatibility issues when mixing JSF RI and Myfaces libraries like Tomahawk, especially on JSF 1.1.

Comment: I don't have had this experience. Are you sure that you didn't accidently put MyFaces JSF libraries in when installing Tomahawk on Sun JSF RI? I've seen this too often with starters. Mixing multiple implementations is indeed troublesome, regardless of which API we're talking about.

Comment: No, definitely not (we're no starters by the way).
I can't tell now what the problems were back then (it's quite a time already), but we were forced to move to MyFaces implementation from JSF RI. We were using Tomahawk as well as few things from Sandbox.

Comment: I started with JSF at the moment RI 1.1_02 was released. It contained *a lot* of bugfixes. Replacing the WSAD-shipped early version of JSF 1.1 with it made a lot of problems disappear instantly.

Comment: I have mixed tomhaw <t:div>,<t:dataTable with JSF RI 1.1 it works fine.I want to add some components from other libraries. that is why asked that question.